What should I specify manually in the path using the option "Config or installation directory" instead of "Do not import settings"?
While configuring Intellij IDEA settings, I'm wondering what should be specified into the option: "Config or installation directory":

At first, I researched this type of the question, checking tutorials, as for instance:

IntelliJ IDEA Tutorial - How to Install and Configure [2020]
IntelliJ IDEA Beginner Tutorial | Download and Setup
How to Setup settings.xml for Intellij and Maven Project | Intellij | Maven
How to Install IntellijIDEA with Java 18 on Windows 10
Configure your intelliJ project
IntelliJ IDEA Tutorial
How to install IntelliJ IDEA on Windows 10/11 (64 bit) [ 2023 Update ] Java 19
JetBrains change location of config and system directories

also I have checked the articles as:

Installing IntelliJ IDEA
IntelliJ configuration directory
Directories used by the IDE

and came to the conclusion it should be specified with idea.properties file in the path:
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.5\bin\idea.properties

Literally, it says:

"In IntelliJ IDEA, configuration files and settings used by the IDE
itself are usually located in the "bin" folder. This folder contains
files that may include:
idea.properties: File for configuring JVM properties and other
environment settings. idea.vmoptions or idea64.vmoptions: File for
configuring Java Virtual Machine options."

But I'm still confusing, because none of provided sources don't answer directly on my question ignoring fully this option as an alternative variant.
I'm looking for any official information from any documentations what should I specify into the option "Config or installation directory", if I don't want to configure using "Do not import settings". And why should it be used there?
To clarify:
I don't consider the "Do not import settings" option at all in this case, because I don’t want to use the default configuration, but choose specifically the one that was applied in one of the versions I was already using.

UPD:
this is probably related to my question, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Thank you in advance for help.
